# get token gmail api get error: "invalid_grant" error_description: "Bad Request"

Tags: javascript, gmail-api

i am trying to get token with gmail api. After login it still can get token

```
access_token: "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
expires_in:3599
refresh_token: 
"xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
scope: "https://mail.google.com/"
token_type: "Bearer"
```

but if i refresh page, it can't get token. it show

```
POST https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v4/token 400
error: "invalid_grant"
error_description: "Bad Request"
```

this is my code:

```
let code = new URLSearchParams(new URL(window.location.href).search).get('code');
const redirect_uri = 'http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%2F12345%2Fmain';
const client_id = 'clientid';
const client_secret = 'Clientsecret';
const tokenEndpoint = 'https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v4/token';
const requestBody = 'grant_type=authorization_code' +'&code='+code +'&redirect_uri='+redirect_uri +'&client_id='+client_id +'&client_secret='+client_secret;
console.log(code);
function get_Access_Token() {
   fetch(tokenEndpoint, {
       method: 'POST',
       headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
       },
       body: requestBody,
       })
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(data => {
           console.log(data);
       })
       .catch(error => {
           console.error( error);
        });
   }
```

i have checked Client_id,Client_secret and redirect_uri is correct

Comment: are you sure the refresh token isnt bad?  What about the time on your pc is that set to NTP?

Comment: I can't get refresh token or access token on page reload